# SQL R Services (jsonlite, curl)

Tags: sql-server, json, r, curl, jsonlite

## Overview

I would like to use SQL R Services to make a call to an API and pull data directly into SQL Server. I've been trying to use jsonlite and curl within R and it's successful from the R GUI, but fails when making the call through SQL Server T-SQL.

### R Script

```
library(jsonlite,curl);
citibike <- fromJSON('http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json');
stations <- citibike$stationBeanList;
stations[,c(2,10)];
```

### SQL Script

```
DECLARE @Rscript NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Rscript = N'library(jsonlite, curl);
    citibike <- fromJSON('+''''+'http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json'+''''+');
     stations <- citibike$stationBeanList;
     OutputDataSet <- subset(stations, select=c("stationName", "stAddress1"))';
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
     @language = N'R',
     @script = @Rscript
    WITH RESULT SETS(([stationName] VARCHAR(500), [stAddress1] VARCHAR(500)));
```

### SQL Error

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
An external script error occurred: 
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server
Calls: source ... fromJSON_string -> parseJSON -> parse_con -> open -> open.connection
In addition: Warning message:
package 'jsonlite' was built under R version 3.3.2 

Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.
```

### Question

Is there another method I should be looking at or is there some simple mistake that is stopping this from working within SQL R Services?

Comment: Note that `library(jsonlite,curl)` is *only* loading `jsonlite`.

Comment: Yes I wasn't implying that this is the source of your problem, but rather it is something additional that is worth fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a firewall rule that only effects SQL R Services, but does not effect running the same script through R GUI or R CLI on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, we setup firewall rules that blocks all outbound network access for R scripts executed from within SQL Server by default. This is done primarily for security reasons and moreover production database systems typically do not have any internet access (this is the setup that we recommend also). Accessing external resources from T-SQL procedures generally is not recommended & it is hard to troubleshoot in case of performance issues (due to say slow website or network share).